# Flutter `flutter build ios --release --flavor staging` doesn't use distribution certificate

Tags: flutter

I want the flutter app for AdHoc.

When hit `flutter build ios --release --flavor staging`, Staging scheme is selected but code sign to Apple Development certificate. Although, I set CODE_SIGN_IDENTITY to Apple Distribution in build settings.

The stragnge log is this (Hide private information).

```
[   +4 ms] executing: security find-identity -p codesigning -v
[ +134 ms]   1) XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "Apple Development: MYNAME (YYYYYYYY)"
             2) XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "Apple Development: MYNAME (XXXXXXXX)"
             3) XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX "Apple Distribution: MYNAME (XXXXXXXX)"
                3 valid identities found
[   +5 ms] Signing iOS app for device deployment using developer identity: "Apple Development: MYNAME (YYYYYYYY)"
```

This is the signing place:

[image]

I tried the build command below. This used Apple Distribution certificate as I expected.

```
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -project /Users/xxxx/Dev/flutter-app/ios/Runner.xcodeproj -scheme Staging -showBuildSettings
```

- Xcode 12.0
- Flutter beta 1.20.2

Why is the non specifying code sing identity selected?

Comment: Searching for https://github.com/flutter/flutter/blob/master/packages/flutter_tools/lib/src/ios/code_signing.dart ... Certificate selections is a bit not good for me..

Comment: I self resolved. The value of DEVELOPMENT_TEAM had multiple values with empty value which I haven't set yet. I change here one value. The build succeeded.